# HTML/PHP and click on disabled button

Tags: php, html, button, click

when bulding page with php.

Should I consider that someone can change disabled button to enabled and then click on it?

Comment: Security checks should be on server-side not just client-side.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't just consider it. You should assume someone will. Something like "disabled" should be done as a service to your visitors. E.g. fill out a form, when all required fields are filled: remove "disabled" - the button can then be clicked.

It won't stop some script kiddo from removing the button's "disabled" attribute and send you hundred's of empty forms just because he's bored.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what your code is, but the short answer is yes. If you care about the integrity of your data you should have validation in place to ensure that what is being submitted is what you want. Disabling a button in the browser is mostly just done to help guide the user through the process. The validation should be done after submission.